# Refinance Mobile Home and add a land purchase to make one loan

Tags: mortgage

I have not bought the land. I have a mobile home that I have a mortgage loan. I would like to create a new loan with both the Mobile home and Land. The plan is to put it on a slab on the land we purchase. It would be nice to have the cost of the slab and move on the loan but that is probably asking too much.

Could I combine the two at the time of purchase of the Land? and Could I add the cost of a slab and the move of the mobile home?

Comment: Since the mobile home can easily be moved, the lender might not want one loan for both.  I’d ask a bank or other mortgage lender.

Comment: Actually once the Manufactured Home is put on a slab it is no longer considered a mobile home it is considered an actual home. So I am wondering if it would be considered a construction loan?

Comment: Your question says "I have a **mobile** home", but your comment says "**Manufactured** Home".  While all mobile homes are manufactured, not every manufactured home is mobile.  The fact that a **mobile** home is **mobile** means that (maybe with some effort) **it can be moved**, even if you plop it down on a slab.

Comment: I have added the word "Home" to the title because at first glance, this question seemed to be about refinancing a _mobile_ (an Indglish word (possibly Brit.English too) for what Americans call a cellphone).

Comment: You can do anything your bank is willing to agree to. The question is what collateral they will accept in a loan. They might accept the combined collateral of land and mobile home, or might not; that's up to them. If they don't, I don't see a lot of disadvantage in having two separate loans outside of another set of closing fees and having to explicitly make two payments each month rather than one.

Answer (score 1):

> Could I add the cost of a slab and the move of the mobile home?

That's not how mortgages work - they're not a "line of credit" that you can just add on whatever costs you decide are part of the property. The bank will look at the *market value* of the land with any "structures" and loan you a portion of that value. If you borrow more than 80% of the total market value, you'll be charged for Private Mortgage Insurance that can be tricky to get rid of.

So if the slab increased the *market* value of the land, you might be able to add in the cost of adding a slab. I doubt the cost of the move could be added to the loan unless you have enough equity to cover the most.

I honestly don't think the bank will let you combine the mobile home and the land into one lone since the "structure" in this case can be removed easily and depreciates much faster than a permanent home would. They may require you to never move the home, or just have the land and mobile home as two different pieces of collateral (meaning they could repossess them if you default) for the loan.

Comment: Actually, once the Mobile home is put on a slab it is no longer considered mobile it is considered and actually home.

Comment: I understand that it probably wouldn't work that way. I am wondering since putting it on a slab makes it permanent, maybe a home construction loan may be considered

Comment: You'll have to talk to the bank - I was assuming the home would still be "mobile" - if that's not the case it _might_ be considered permanent by the bank.  I'll delete my answer shortly since it appears to be based on a faulty premise.